# Add members to Outlook GAL Distribution List using C# in a Console app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, gal, distribution-list

I'm trying to write a C# console app that can programmatically update an Outlook distribution list (DL) in the Global Address List (GAL).  I have permission to update this DL.  I can do it interactively on my PC using Outlook, and I can do it in Perl code using `Win32::NetAdmin::GroupAddUsers`.

After adding a reference to COM library "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library", and then accessed via:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

I can successfully read from a DL, even recursing through DL's inside the "main" DL being searched.  Here's that working code (critiques not needed for this piece):

```
private static List<Outlook.AddressEntry> GetMembers(string dl, bool recursive)
{
    try
    {
        List<Outlook.AddressEntry> memberList = new List<Outlook.AddressEntry>();

        Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.AddressEntry dlEntry = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries[dl];
        if (dlEntry.Name == dl)
        {
            Outlook.AddressEntries members = dlEntry.Members;
            foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry member in members)
            {
                if (recursive && (member.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry))
                {
                    List<Outlook.AddressEntry> sublist = GetMembers(member.Name, true);
                    foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry submember in sublist)
                    {
                        memberList.Add(submember);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    memberList.Add(member);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not find an exact match for '" + dl + "'.");
            Console.WriteLine("Closest match was '" + dlEntry.Name +"'.");
        }

        return memberList;
    }
    catch
    {
        // This mostly fails if running on a PC without Outlook.
        // Return a null, and require the calling code to handle it properl
        // (or that code will get a null-reference excception).
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can use the output of that to examine the members closely, so I think I understand the DL/member objects a bit.

But, the following code will NOT add a member to a DL:

```
private static void AddMembers(string dl)
{
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.AddressEntry ae = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries[dl];
    try {
        ae.Members.Add("EX", "Tuttle, James", "/o=EMC/ou=North America/cn=Recipients/cn=tuttlj");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    ae.Update();
}
```

The arguments to `Members.Add()` are defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb623616(v=office.14).aspx), and the values shown in my code come exactly from examining my own Member object from another DL.

The exception displayed is simply "The bookmark is not valid."  A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723575) was asked before, but the solution was to use P/Invoke or LDAP.  I really have no idea how to use P/Invoke (strictly a C# and Perl programmer, not a Windows/C/C++ programmer), and I don't have access to the LDAP server, so I really want to get this working through the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` objects.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with several different .NET objects, using `System.DirectorServices.AccountManagement` as posted in [Adding and removing users from Active Directory groups in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143052) is what finally code this working for me.  Closing out my own question.